# Simple ASP.Net MessageBox?

Tags: asp.net

I want a simple MessageBox for ASP.Net, but everything I tried didn't work and I don't know why.
The last thing I tried was [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WebMsgBox09082006110929AM/WebMsgBox.aspx) but it didn't work either.

Any ideas for a simple messagebox with work safe?

For more information:

- I can't bind anything to a button
- I must call it from the Code Behind
- Directly after clicking okay, I must have a redirect

---

Test it with onClick on the button:

```
                    string msg = "Text";
                    string script = "<script language=JavaScript>alert("+msg+");</script>";
                    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "clientScript", script);
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: All, in case my answer isn't sufficient, it seems Kovu wants to have the alert be added after the button is clicked, not before. I'm not sure why he wants to do it - be it being afraid of view source, not having information until after the click, or what - but it's his requirement and he seems adamant about it.

Comment: I don't understand the problem, but yes, I want an aler after button click. There are a lot of database checks and under specific conditions I will show a message box. Thats it.

Comment: I'm sorry but your code is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the dialog component from [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) to display a message box.
A simple usage demo is available [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-message).

Comment: Try, but not succeeded, I implement all correct but no idea how to use. The demo is for beignners with Jquery very less usefull.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your answer.

http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Message-Box.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
string s = "here in button event";
            string script = "<script language=JavaScript>alert('" + s + "');</script>";
            if (!Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("clientScript"))
            {
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "clientScript", script);
        }

        }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this using ajax? Is this attached to a server side event that's called when the user clicks a button?

If so, ajax only sends data that's associated with the updatepanel in question. If so, try this ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript((Control)ctlControl, ctlControl.GetType(), "ClientScript", "alert('foo')", true); 
It is important that the ctlControl is inside the updatepanel being updated.

If you are not using ajax, is ClientScript registered elsewhere with RegisterClientScriptBlock? The client name has to be unique for every registry or it will think you are calling the same code twice.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't unterstand, what is ctlControl?
I don't use an update panel, I simple use a Button!

Comment: If you aren't using ajax, i wouldn't worry about it. Your problem was a common issue with ajaxpanels and updatescripts, but if you aren't using it, that wouldn't be the culprit. However, since you asked... ctlControl is a reference to a control on your page. If you are using updatepanels, the ClientScriptblock needs to know what section of the page the alert is tied to so it only sends it when needed.

Comment: Saar updated his/her question again to suit your needs. The only thing he left out was that you need to add OnClick="Button1_click" on your ascx page for it to work so it looks something like this - <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click"  Text="btn"/>

If his/her code doesn't work, first try calling clientScript something else (you may have used it before). If it doesn't work after that, there's a larger underlying issue that needs to be resolved that we can work through with patience.